# Error de conexion con SQLServer

Tags: java, sql-server

A la hora de conectar mi programa de java con SQLServer me tira un error de conexion que no eh podido solucionar e intentando cambiar el puerto y nada y el codigo de error es:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL). Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:af608cef-b476-4ddc-a0f6-45a8a5993a45
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc@10.2.0.jre11/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3680)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc@10.2.0.jre11/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:2113)
```

Código de la conexión que lanza la excepción a la hora de la conexión:

```
public class Conexion {
private static Connection conexion = null;
private static PreparedStatement pstm; //NO es tan seguro ya que permite SQL Injection, se recomienda PreparedStatement

public Conexion(int valor) {}
private Conexion() {
    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba;user=Lucy;password=gulf1;";
        try {
            Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            System.out.println("Si jala");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error de DRIVER");
    }
}

public static Connection getConexion(){

     if (conexion == null){
         new Conexion();
     }

     return conexion;
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade la parte de código como texto plano y no como un imagen.

Comment: Listo amigo ya añadí el código

Comment: [¿Leíste este artículo?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification/ba-p/2591304). Si no encuentras ahí la solución danos más detalles del contexto: ubicación de la bd (local o remota), si usas llaves públicas/privadas, si usas certificados y has comprobado si los mismos son válidos. etc.